# Locating rows from dataframe with list of words

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

How can I select rows from a dataframe using a list of words as a reference?

E.g. I have a dataframe, `df_business`, and each item in the last column is a string containing comma-separated categories, like this:

```
categories: "Restaurants, Burgers, Coffee & Tea, Fast Food, Food"
```

I tried this, but it only gives me the rows for the businesses containing ONLY the word coffee in their categories:

```
bus_int = df_business.loc[(df_business['categories'].isin(['Coffee']))]
```

How can I get the businesses containing my word even when it's present among others, as shown above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the [`contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) method:

```py
bus_int = df_business.loc[df_business.categories.str.contains('Coffee', regex=False)]
```

(The default is to treat the supplied argument as a regular expression, which you don't need if you're simply looking for a substring like this.)

Comment: adding na=False made it work perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Just use - .isin(List_name/the string you want)**

Example -

```
list = ['apple', 'mango', 'banana'] #creating a list

df[df['Fruits_name'].isin(list)] 
# this will find all the rows with this 3 fruit name
```