# Filter df to remove rows where a column has a word/phrase

Tags: pandas, dataframe, contains

I have a list of words and phrases which I want to use to specify which rows to remove when creating a new dataframe.

```
include = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3'...]
exclude = ['word4', 'word5 word6' ...]
```

So far I have basically tried:

```
new_df = []

for word in include:
    valid = df['Message'].str.contains(word)
    count = 0
    for item in valid:
        if item:
            temp.append(df.iloc[count])
        count += 1
```

Then I remove the extras using `temp = pd.DataFrame(temp)` and `temp = temp.drop_duplicates`.

This gives me the included dataframe but then I want to further specify that if they contain any word from excluded that the row should be dropped. I am not very skilled with Pandas and have tried the same concept just with `~` for valid and `.drop()` instead of `.append()` but the rows still remain, how could I go about this?

Comment: You might find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65525712/5570498

Answer (score 0):

I assume the words will be embedded in a bigger text, if not, you should consider the Pandas method `df['Message'].isin(list_of_words)`

For the first case you can either do it with regex patterns or without regex patterns and use `reduce` to combine all the masks (lists of boolean values)

**Example without regex pattern**

```
import pandas as pd
from operator import or_
from functools import reduce

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Message': [
            'word1 aaa',
            'word1 word4',
            'word4',
            'word3aaa'
        ]
    }
)

include_words_list = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
exclude_words_list = ['word4', 'word5', 'word6']

include_rows_mask = reduce(or_, [df['Message'].str.contains(word, regex=False) for word in include_words_list])
exclude_rows_mask = reduce(or_, [df['Message'].str.contains(word, regex=False) for word in exclude_words_list])

selected_rows_mask = (include_rows_mask) & ~(exclude_rows_mask)

df_selected = df.loc[selected_rows_mask, :]
```

**Example with regex pattern**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Message': [
            'word1 aaa',
            'word1 word4',
            'word4',
            'word3aaa'
        ]
    }
)

include_words_pattern= '(word1|word2|word3)'
exclude_words_pattern = '(word4|word5|word6)'

include_rows_mask = df['Message'].str.contains(include_words_pattern, regex=True)
exclude_rows_mask = df['Message'].str.contains(exclude_words_pattern, regex=True)

selected_rows_mask = (include_rows_mask) & ~(exclude_rows_mask)

df_selected = df.loc[selected_rows_mask, :]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not now about the regex function, thanks again for taking the time!